# Hack IE 8 back button / force resend?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cache-control, browser-history

When I go back with IE 8 I get the error

> "Webpage has expired 
>          Most likely cause: •The local copy of this webpage is out of date,
>   and the website requires that you
>   download it again.
>        What you can try: 
>        Click on the Refresh button on the toolbar to reload the page. After
>   refreshing, you might need to navigate
>   to the specific webpage again, or
>   re-enter information."

Which is absolutely correct since we do not allow caching of our web sites.
In ff we get a message:

> To display this page, Firefox must
>   send information that will repeat any
>   action (such as a search or order
>   confirmation) that was performed
>   earlier.
>
> [Resend]   -  [Cancel]

A resend leads to our neat errorpage stating that these kind of resends are not allowed.
This page does not show in IE8  since i guess IE 8 is not smart enough for resending these forms. Is there a workaround? 
Even a hack to disable the IE 8 back button would be welcomed

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Warning: page has expired" error in IE when hitting "back" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590383/warning-page-has-expired-error-in-ie-when-hitting-back-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This have been asked many times - I [here at SO too](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=back+reload+expired+post)

["Warning: page has expired" error in IE when hitting "back" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590383/warning-page-has-expired-error-in-ie-when-hitting-back-button)

1: change POST to GET OR

2: send a redirect to a normal page - either with a response.redirect or a location.replace javascript

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: yes it's been asked many times, I think my question was badly formulated, sorry for that.
1 and 2: with jsf 1.2 you cannot simply push a button to replace post with get. Our application is built for post (we are talking of about roughly 700 pages) and we cannot change that. Further more the user is never supposed to go back with the history - the browsers history was not taken into consideration during design.
Bottom line: a hack to disable the back button / delete the browsing history would be fine